# Python predict from data by argv (type error)

Tags: python, arguments

I'm try to predict a data with:

```
joblib_model_mlp.predict(sc.transform(np.array([data])))
```

my *data* is: `data = sys.argv[1]` 
and I pass this list as argument:

> python script.py
> [3,2554,51,49,853,1,4,2,8,11,2,2,2,2501,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,2,2,0,3,3]

but i get back:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:
> '[3,2554,51,49,853,1,4,2,8,11,2,2,2,2501,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,2,2,0,3,3]'

if I set in my script, all work as well.

```
data = [3,2554,51,49,853,1,4,2,8,11,2,2,2,2501,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,2,2,0,3,3]
```

i don't understand how can I fix.

Comment: the argument will be a `str` object, you need to parse that into whatever data structure you require, if not a string.

Comment: please add as answer. Solved with 
mylist = data.split(",")

print('List')
print(mylist)
data = mylist

Answer (score 0):

Given the example you have provided, `sys.argv[1]` is not a `list` but rather a `str` instance.

You can parse this `str` representing a `list` into a `list` instance using the [builtin `json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

See example below.

```py
import json
import sys

data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
```

Here `json.loads(sys.argv[1])` parses the `str` passed as the first argument at runtime into an appropriate Python object based on [this conversion table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table).

Given the example provided in your original question (`[3,2554,51,49,853,1,4,2,8,11,2,2,2,2501,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,2,2,0,3,3]`), the object returned is a Python `list`.